# Scraping Address & Phone Number & Map

Tags: php, regex

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="fiche-detail">
      <div class="ColG">
         <div class="ColG1">
            <div class="bloc-info">
               <h2 class="titre filet-bottom3">Coordinates</h2>
               <p>
                  555, avenue du Pont Nord<br />
                  Alma, Québec<br />
                  G8B6T5                                  
               </p>
               <p>
                  Phone number&nbsp;: 418 668-4657                   <br />
                  Fax&nbsp;:  418 668-2770                   
               </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

loaded from:
http://www.saq.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SAQStoreLocatorSearchResultsStoreDetailsView?storeLocationId=10374&catalogId=50000&langId=-1&storeIdentifier=33632&storeId=20002

I'm trying to extract the following details and load them into a 'storedetails' array:

1. Street Number (555)
2. Street (avenue du Pont Nord)
3. City (Alma)
4. State (Québec)
5. Postal Code (G8B6T5)
6. Phone number
7. Fax
8. Coordinates (from the js at the bottom, also loaded from that page above)

Is regex the only solution or is there a better way to go do this, knowing each address could be different in length, at least.

If regex is the only way, is it possible to get some pointers. I'm not sure how far into the tags I should start. Like from  because this is the first instance of this specific tag from the top down.

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
      var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(48.55970, -71.63980);
      var optionsList = {
         zoom: 16,
         center: mapCenter,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("GoogleMap"), optionsList);

      var storeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: mapCenter,
         map: map,
         icon: image
      });
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to use a regex parser to extract each `<p>` of interest, and then use a regex to tease apart the various address components.

Comment: Hi, so I came up with the following: (\d+), (\D+),\s(\D+)<br \/>\s+(\D\d\D\d\D\d)\s+<\/p>\s+<p>. Seems to get most I want. Another question is it possible output each of the regex matched group enclosed by () into the array I was talking about. Tried to google but can't seem to get the right keywords.

Comment: @Senri Do you want to extract data from `HTML` using `PHP` ?

Answer (score 0):

In general its **very dangerous** to read the data from the plain HTML of an webpage and you should not do it when you have other possibilities. The big problem is that you never know when the webpage will be changed or if the data that you get is correctly structured.

In your example you do not know that the data will have the given structure:

```
[STREET_NR], [STREET]<br />
[CITY], [STATE]<br />
[POST_CODE]
```

Therefor the best way is to contact SAQ and ask if they provide an API.